# Not able to access dynamodb tables via DAX cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Created a cluster `[cluster name : staging-dax-cluster.ckbrjt.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com]` in us-east-1 region . When i try to use the cluster getting the below exceptions.

The common lib logging backed is deprecated. Switch to the slf4j backend.
Cloud Watch appender is no longer supported. Use the stdOut appender or SLF4J backed.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazon.dax.client.exceptions.DaxServiceException: NotImplementedException
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ExceptionTranslator.createValidationException(ExceptionTranslator.java:91)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ExceptionTranslator.translateException(ExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.DaxClient.handleException(DaxClient.java:1898)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.DaxClient.describeTable(DaxClient.java:610)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient$21.call(ClusterDaxClient.java:328)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient$21.call(ClusterDaxClient.java:325)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient$RetryHandler.makeRequestWithRetries(ClusterDaxClient.java:635)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient.makeReadRequestWithRetries(ClusterDaxClient.java:604)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient.describeTable(ClusterDaxClient.java:325)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableHelper.verifyTableExists(TableHelper.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableHelper.verifyOrCreateTable(TableHelper.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.transactions.TransactionManager.verifyOrCreateTransactionTable(TransactionManager.java:180)
    at com.usermind.integrations.api.dao.DynamoDbPersistenceContext.verifyOrCreateTransactionTables(DynamoDbPersistenceContext.java:151)
    at com.usermind.integrations.api.dao.DynamoDbPersistenceContext.<init>(DynamoDbPersistenceContext.java:138)
    at com.usermind.integrations.api.App.initPersistenceContext(App.java:143)
    at com.usermind.integrations.api.AbstractSparkApp.run(AbstractSparkApp.java:17)
    at com.usermind.integrations.api.App.main(App.java:93)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAX doesn't recognize DynamoDB operations for managing tables, in your case "describeTable". Read and write operations are supported. See [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.concepts.html) for detailed APIs.

Comment: thanks for the above information. when i try to use dax for getItem i face `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted exception`.

Comment: what is the difference between AmazonDaxClient and DaxClient. Which one should we use for cache read operation for dynamodb

Comment: AmazonDaxClient is the interface to substitute AmazonDynamoDB. DaxClient is an implementation of AmazonDaxClient interface. However, DaxClient is a single node client, which you typically shouldn't use. You should use ClusterDaxClient instead, which is also an implementation of AmazonDaxClient interface, but contains load balancing and health check logic for the DAX cluster. For more information on how to use ClusterDaxClient, please see [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.modify-your-app.html)

Comment: I think what might be confusing is that there are two AmazonDaxClient definitions. com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.AmazonDaxClient is an *interface* to substitute AmazonDynamoDB interface. This is what you should use to substitute DynamoDB read and write operations. com.amazonaws.services.dax.AmazonDaxClient is a *class* for DAX cluster provisioning operations, create cluster, describe cluster, etc...

Comment: Can we use DynamoDBMapper for DaxClient? if No then what should be the replacement?

Answer (score 0):

- DAX doesn't supports manage table operations, like `DescribeTable`.
- This is quite weird because when we define the DAX access control through IAM, [Refer AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.access-control.html); no matter the specific operation we need support for (eg: Only Read, Both Read and Write, etc); adding the action: dynamodb:DescribeTable is mandatory.
- Because: the `dynamodb:DescribeTable` action is required for DAX to maintain metadata about the table.
- But we cannot call the DescribeTable API through DAX client, as it it not supported. We still need to define it in IAM Policy (and in turn IAC) because it uses it beneath the hood as explained above.